# Qual é a finalidade do caminho "/dev/null" em alguns comandos?

Tags: linux

Muitas vezes, já vi algumas pessoas ensinando fazer alguns comandos (principalmente relacionado a saídas de texto ou coisas do tipo), onde é utilizado esse diretório ou arquivo chamado `/dev/null`.

Exemplo:

```
  wget -qO- $url &> /dev/null
```

- Qual é a finalidade desse `/dev/null`?
- O que ele é? Um diretório ou um arquivo?
- Por que alguns comandos (como no exemplo acima) usam ele?

Comment: o **buraco negro** do linux? tudo que vai pra la some :D

Comment: Qual é o problema com a pergunta? O que ela pode ser melhorada?

Comment: Não vi problemas na pergunta. Aliás, é uma ótima pergunta e que desenvolvedores em geral deveriam saber. Afinal de contas, faz parte do desenvolvimento WEB saber pra que server o wget e porque o /dev/null é utilizado nesse caso.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Antes da explicação técnica, uma metáfora. Sabe quando você envia um email para uma grande empresa reclamando de um produto e não recebe absolutamente nenhuma resposta, esse é o famoso caso onde o seu email caiu no `/dev/null`, ou seja, alguém viu e deixou pra lá (ou provavelmente nem viu) e você ficou sem sua resposta.

O `/dev/null` é um arquivo especial. Você pode redirecionar saídas pra este dispositivo e o conteúdo será intencionalmente descartado. O redirecionamento para o `/dev/null` sempre reporta sucesso na escrita.

Como dito pelo @GuilhermeLautert nos comentários, o `/dev/null` é conhecido como Buraco Negro por causa disso.

No contexto do exemplo do `wget`, o `/dev/null` é utilizado, pois não é necessário fazer download do conteúdo para um arquivo, o objetivo é apenas fazer uma requisição para uma determinada URL. O conteúdo será obviamente transmitido do servidor para o computador que executou o wget, mas como existe o `-O` no comando, a saída será redirecionada para o `/dev/null`.

Comment: Boa explicação +1

Answer (score -4):

'Os sistemas mais atuais fornecem um diretório chamado /dev/fd, cujos arquivos são 0,1, 2, etc.. Abrir o arquivo /dev/fd/i equivale a duplicar o descritor i (assumindo que o descritor i está aberto).(...)'

Direcionar a saida de um comando para um descritor nulo, implica num estado de loop infinito, mantendo o processo atual indefinidamente, pois mantem a saida do comando aberta, impossibilitando seu fim. Elegante ou não, uma ferramenta útil ao seu propósito.

[Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment, Stevens, W. Richard]

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: `/dev/fd` é um link simbólico a [`/proc/self/fd`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html), que é apenas uma introspecção dos identificadores de arquivo que seu programa abriu. Você abre um identificador de arquivo, obtém uma nova entrada nesse diretório. `exec 3>somefile.txtin` shell criará assim um `/dev/fd/3`, porque ele foi aberto `somefile.txte` usado `dup2()` para renumerar qualquer número de descritor atribuído automaticamente ao qual foi dado 3. [Texto original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48739520/how-to-add-new-file-descriptors-under-dev-fd#comment84479099_48739520)

Comment: Quanto ao texto *"...Direcionar a saída de um comando para um descritor nulo, implica num estado de loop infinito..."* o autor está se referindo ao uso dum redirecionamento `> /dev/fd/i` onde `i` é um descritor numérico não existente portanto um descritor nulo(inválido), portanto o trecho que copiou não possui relação alguma com a questão levantada *Qual é a finalidade do caminho "/dev/null" em alguns comandos?*